# when use cygwin g++ to build a project , can't find the include head file even if I have indicated path with -I

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, cygwin

I knew there a punch of this kind problem to bother you . But it's weird to me . Please be patient to let me finish my problem statement .

Background : Windows vista , cygwin latest version , opencv 2.4.3

My project make file like this as opencv was installed in d:\Application\OpenCV2.4.3\opencv :

```
OPENCV=/cygdrive/d/Application/OpenCV2.4.3/opencv/build
CUSTOM_INCLUDES+=-I${OPENCV}/include -I${OPENCV}/include/opencv -I${OPENCV}/include/opencv2/ml -I${OPENCV}/include/opencv2/highgui -I${SRC_DIR}
CUSTOM_LIBRARIES+= -L${OPENCV}/x86/mingw/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_objdetect
```

And a head file need to build was like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core_c.h>
blablabla...
```

When I execute :

```
g++ -c src/ObjectDetector.cpp -Wall  -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops   -I/cygdrive/d/Application/OpenCV2.4.3/opencv/build/include -I/cygdrive/d/Application/OpenCV2.4.3/opencv/build/include/opencv -I/cygdrive/d/Application/OpenCV2.4.3/opencv/build/include/opencv2/ml -I/cygdrive/d/Application/OpenCV2.4.3/opencv/build/include/opencv2/highgui -Isrc/ -o build/ObjectDetector.o
```

Oops, it turn out :

```
    In file included from src/ObjectDetector.cpp:10:0:
src/ObjectDetector.h:15:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
```

**I am 100 persent sure opencv2/core/core.hpp was in the  /cygdrive/d/Application/OpenCV2.4.3/opencv/build/include** , and use "" substitute for <> . None of these works , I am pained . I have referenced every google search item . pls help me out .

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to mix a MinGW-compiled OpenCV with Cygwin; that won't work.  If you want to use OpenCV on Cygwin, Try installing the `libopencv-devel` package from [Cygwin Ports](http://cygwinports.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but I figure out that its just a compiler problem . When I use Mingw tool to make libraries , it works .